# i am facing error while installing mpop module of python

Tags: python

I have installed built up tools for visual studio still not able to solve the error.
[error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2]

how to solve the error?